# How to getting value from itemlist HTML and processed in a flask

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, bootstrap-4

I'am Trying to getting value if user choose an item 1 it show the value from array in flask and i want to calculate it also in flask. here's my code

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label for="firstname">Activity Contribution  {{i+1}}</label>  
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" onchange="check()">  
    <option selected>Choose...</option> 
    <option value="20">Book</option>  
    <option value="12">Pencils</option>  
    <option value="1">Eraser</option>  
  </select>  
</div>  

<input type="text" placeholder="QTY">    
<input type="text" placeholder="Total" disabled>
```

Flask Code

```
@app.route('/detail', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def hello33(): 
# i have no idea how to do this  
i = inputgroupselect * qty     
return render_template ('Detail.html', price=price)
```

i expect when i choose book and fill qty 5, it will show 100 in the total box without click the button

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reload the page. you need to use Javascript. or if you don't care about the page reload you need to send a post form to flask to receive the data.

When you send the HTML with flask. the user receive the page and flask can't do nothing until the user send another request.